# How to get ouput results in R shiny app for logistic regression on my data

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a R shiny app that performs a logistic regression on input data and gives and appended column with its results to the input data,the input data is of four columns and my 5th column is predicted results.

Thank you!!

I'm a beginner and and trying to learn R and the R shiny app,i've modified and tried the below code whick i have copied from Fisseha Berhane https://datascience-enthusiast.com/R/shiny_ML.html

The result column will predict either a customer of a gym chooses 1month or a 3month package.

```
library(caret)
library(shiny)
library(LiblineaR)
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
load("C:/Users/Sampath/Desktop/PROJECT/LogisticRegression.rda")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 800*1024^2)   
    output$sample_input_data_heading = renderUI({   
    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile)){
        return(NULL)
    }else{
        tags$h4('Sample data')
    }
  })

  output$sample_input_data = renderTable({    
      inFile <- input$file1

      if (is.null(inFile)){
          return(NULL)
      }else{
      input_data =readr::read_csv(input$file1$datapath, col_names = TRUE)

      colnames(input_data) = c("age", "Gender","height","weight","Label")

      input_data$Label = as.factor(input_data$Label )

      levels(input_data$Label) <- c("1","3")
      head(input_data)
    }
  })

  predictions<-reactive({

    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile)){
      return(NULL)
    }else{
      withProgress(message = 'Predictions in progress. Please wait ...', {
        input_data =  readr::read_csv(input$file1$datapath, col_names = TRUE)

        colnames(input_data) = c("age", "Gender","height","weight","Label")

        input_data$Label = as.factor(input_data$Label )
        input_data$age=as.integer(input_data$age)
        levels(input_data$Label) <- c("1","3")

        #mapped = feature_mapping(input_data)

        #df_final = cbind(input_data, mapped)
        prediction = predict(classifier,input_data[c(1:4)])

        input_data_with_prediction = cbind(input_data,prediction )
        input_data_with_prediction

      })
    }
  })


 output$sample_prediction_heading = renderUI({  
    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile)){
      return(NULL)
    }else{
      tags$h4('Sample predictions')
    }
  })

  output$sample_predictions = renderTable({ 
    predictions


  })

  })

  # Downloadable csv of predictions ----

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("input_data_with_prediction", ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(predictions(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    })

})
```

The expected output is an 5th column with predicted results
but i keep on getting the errors

error1:-object 'X' not found

error2:-cannot coerce class ‘c("reactiveExpr", "reactive")’ to a data.frame